# mysql root password rest

Tags: mysql, passwords, root

For some reason, the script below doesn't reset the root password. The script works in that it performs the steps, but when I try to log back in to mysql as root with the new password, it doesn't recognize the change and insists I use the old one.

Here is the script below:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Resetting root password"
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sleep 2


if [ -f /root/mysql.reset.sql ]; then
    rm -f /root/mysql.reset.sql
    touch /root/mysql.reset.sql
else
    touch /root/mysql.reset.sql
fi

echo "UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('akimbo') WHERE User='root'; FLUSH        
PRIVILEGES;" >> /root/mysql.reset.sql
mysqld_safe --init-file=/root/mysql.reset.sql &
/etc/init.d/mysql start
sleep 2

echo "Done setting mysql password for user root. Password is password."
```

So when I try mysql -uroot -pakimbo it complains and only works when i use the old password.

Any ideas?

cheers

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use the `mysqladmin` command?

`mysqladmin -u root -p'oldpassword' password newpass`

This can also be used for changing other user's passwords as well:

`mysqladmin -u sql_username -p oldpassword password newpass`

Comment: Well when I do a fresh install it seems to remember the user credentials from old which is strange. but I dont know what the old password is upon a fresh install so I have to use a method where I dont need to specify the old password.

Comment: Stop the mysqld server, add `skip-grant-tables=1` to `my.cnf` under `[mysqld]`, start the mysqld server, connect using `mysql -u root` and do `use mysql;` then do `UPDATE user SET Password = PASSWORD('new_pwd') WHERE User = 'root';`, clean up my.cnf and restart the mysqld server, test with `mysql -u root -p` by entering your new password at the prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do it from SQL use mysqladmin as in the manual

```
shell> mysqladmin -u root password "newpwd"
shell> mysqladmin -u root -h host_name password "newpwd"
```

Answer (score 0):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

There's a --skip-grant-tables option you can run on startup.  Then connect as root, reset your password and then restart w/o the skip grant option