# MySQL change root password. Find root username

Tags: php, mysql, centos, debian

I am a beginner and I have two servers. One is Debian based and one is CentOS based.

I tried lots of methods (listed below) and from other websites but I didn't find how to change the root password of MySQL or even to find out the root username.

How can I do this for both servers?

**Related questions which not helped me:**

- [reset/change mysql root password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28341788/reset-change-mysql-root-password)
- [How to change mysql root password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517410/how-to-change-mysql-root-password)
- [mysql root password rest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8829024/mysql-root-password-rest)
- [reset/change mysql root password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28341788/reset-change-mysql-root-password)
- [How to change the mysql root password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8789522/how-to-change-the-mysql-root-password)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27262883/cant-change-mysql-root-password
- [MySQL root password change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534056/mysql-root-password-change)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### 1. FIND ROOT USERNAME

The root username is always `root`.

### 2. HOW TO CHANGE DEFAULT ROOT PASSWORD

**Connect to your server using console**
And then:

**Stop MySQL**

*If you are using Ubuntu or Debian:*

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

*For CentOS, Fedora, and RHEL:*

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

**Start MySQL in safe mode**

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
```

**Login (without any password)**

```
mysql -u root
```

**Select the database**

```
use mysql;
```

**Change password**

```
update user set password=PASSWORD("YOUR NEW PASSWORD HERE") where User='root';
```

**Flush Privileges (like refresh)**

```
flush privileges;
```

**Exit**

```
quit
```

or

```
exit
```

**Restart MySQL**
*Ubuntu and Debian*

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
```

and

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

*CentOS, Fedora and RHEL*

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
```

and

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

**Password changed successfully!**

Now, you can try to login with the new password:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

(type the password when prompted)

Hope this helps!

Comment: So, the username is root?

Comment: Yes, it is always `root`.